# Need to explain the term [0] == ![0]

Tags: javascript

what does the term `[0] == ![0]` means? Though they return `true`.But i need to explain how it returns `true` as type of [0] is object and ![0] returns boolean? So how they are equal? Thanks

Comment: Did you mean JavaScript? If not, how is this related to jQuery?

Comment: `==` doesn't compare types

Comment: Why so many close-as-dupe votes? This is not a dupe of that.

Comment: Why are people even talking about `===`? This has nothing to do with the difference between `==` and `===`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`![0]` is simply `false`, since all non-`null` objects cast to `true`.

When comparing `[0]` and `false`, they are converted to numbers - don't ask why, that's just the way it is. `[0]` is first converted to the string `"0"` (arrays cast to strings by concatenating the entries with `,` for a separator), which is then the number `0`. `false` is cast to the number `0`, and there you have it: `[0] == ![0]` is equivalent to `0 == 0`, which is true.

Answer (score 7):

To understand this, go through `![0]` expression first. It evaluates to `false` - as `[0]` (as any Object in JS) is a truthy value. So the statement becomes...

`[0] == false`

Now it's easier: `false` is converted to `0` (for Boolean -> Number rule), and `[0]` is converted by Object-To-Primitive rule - first to `'0'` (String), then to `0` (Number). Obviously, `0` *is* equal to `0`. )

P.S. And yes, it may seem quite weird, but both...

`[0] == false`

... and ...

`![0] == false`

... evaluate to `true`: the former is already explained, the latter is just `false == false`. Anyone still surprised by those `==` Lint warnings? )

Answer (score -1):

You have split the expression into multiple parts:

```
typeof([0]) // "object"
[0] == true // false
![0] == true // false
![0] == false // true
```

The reason for this because in JavaScript only the value `1` is implicitly converted to true, so all other values are converted to false. The `![0]` only negates a false expression thus it becomes `(false == false) == true`.

Comment: `only the value 1 is implicitly converted to true` - what? Actually, it's right the opposite: Boolean is converted to Number in comparisons.

Comment: What do you mean by "only the value 1 is implicitly converted to true"? That seems... not correct? Otherwise, a not unreasonable answer.